# checking internet connection in c++ using internetcheckconnection

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wininet, winelib

I am trying to check internet connection of the user by using `internetcheckconnection()`.

The code:

```
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

int main()
{

    char url[128];
    strcat(url, "http://www.techtoolbox.com");
    bool bConnect = InternetCheckConnection(url, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0);

    if (bConnect) {
        //internet connection exists !

        std::cout << "yes";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "no ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But many error are coming up like

> 29    11  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\Wininet.h [Error] 'LPVOID' does not name a type
>
> 30    11  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\Wininet.h [Error] 'HINTERNET' does not name a type
>
> 32 11  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\Wininet.h [Error] 'WORD' does not name a type
> and 431 more .

I have already installed Wininet.lib, but still these error are coming . It would be kind of you if you could solve this easy problem :) .

Comment: If it's robust enough for you, you could try pinging some well known website...

Comment: It should be `strcpy`, not `strcat`

Comment: @ZivS Pinging doesn't help , i tried already .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPVOID`, `HINTERNET` and other types from your error messages are declared in `windows.h`. You should rearrange includes to fix these errors:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
```